# Render partial views inside main view in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have 4 views under Views/Shared folder.

1. Attendance Track.cshtml (Main View)
2. _Attendance.cshtml (Partial view)
3. _Leaves.cshtml (Partial view)
4. _Efforts.cshtml (Partial view)

Trying to render the 3 views in Main View,but not able to render.Don't know where am doing wrong.
Code in Main view to render partial views:

```
<div id="RenderAttendance">
 @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_Attendance.cshtml");
</div>
<div id="RenderLeaves" >
 @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_Leaves.cshtml");
</div>
<div id="RenderEfforts" >
 @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_Efforts.cshtml");
</div>
```

Comment: What does "unable to render" mean? Any error message? Or views just don't show up on the page? Also, are these views strongly typed?

Comment: Views dont show up on page.BUt Partial views are rendering when a name is mentioned on the main view's controller

Comment: Are you sure they are not rendering? did you inspected the page? Also, put a break point and see whether that part is being executed.

Comment: Its not a strongly typed view.When am trying to put a breakpoint not accepting it.(Breakpoint cannot be placed at this point)

Comment: You can put break point at `@Html.Partial("...` or within the partial view you can put a dummy block for the purpose of debugging.

Comment: For shared partial view no need to provide the path as by default it will be searched in shared folder

Comment: try @{Html.Patial("View Name");}

Comment: @Girish : tried the solution:An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code
 The partial view '_Attendance.cshtml' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. But _attendance.cshtml is under shared folder

Comment: You should not write the extension i.e. the view name should be just _attendance and not _attendance.cshtml, use @{Html.Patial("_Attendance");}

Comment: @{Html.RenderPartial("_Attendance");}

Comment: @Girish: Tried but no hopes:( Dont know where am going wrong

Comment: Could you please put the content of the _Attendance.cshtml partial view, and just try one partial view at a time, let start with _Attendance. <div id="RenderAttendance">
 @{Html.RenderPartial("_Attendance")};
</div>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hai please try like below

```
<div id="RenderAttendance">
 @Html.Partial("_Attendance");
</div>
<div id="RenderLeaves" >
 @Html.Partial("_Leaves");
</div>
<div id="RenderEfforts" >
 @Html.Partial("_Efforts");
</div>
```

**Note : If your partial views contains a model class means try the below one**

```
<div id="RenderAttendance">
 @Html.Partial("_Attendance", new ModelClassName());
</div>
<div id="RenderLeaves" >
 @Html.Partial("_Leaves", new ModelClassName_2());
</div>
<div id="RenderEfforts" >
 @Html.Partial("_Efforts", new ModelClassName_3());
</div>
```

Comment: :Hi RenderAttendance is working & other two partial views are not rendering.

Comment: your solution worked for me.Thank you soooo much @ Aravindan.

Answer (score 1):

My Partial View was named "*Grid*" in a folder called "*Control*" right under the "*Views*" directory.
I had to use:

```
@Html.Partial("/Views/Control/Grid")
```

Once I did this, MVC was able to load it then.
Yes, I realize I should prefix my partial views with an Underscore, but because I organize them all under the "Control" folder, that's my way of denoting their purpose.
As I migrate from Web Forms to MVC, it helps me to think of Partial Views as reusable Custom User Controls I add to Full Page Views.